# SQL Update Where Select

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I want to update "time 2" row, in the user's last "time 1" entry. I was try this, but not function.

```
UPDATE `temp` SET `time2`=NOW() WHERE user = 'kraso' (SELECT max(time1) FROM 'temp')
```

Comment: You did not specify your RDBMS, but how about something like `UPDATE 'temp' SET 'time2'=NOW() WHERE user = 'kraso' and time1 = (SELECT max(time1) FROM 'temp' where user = 'kraso')`

Comment: thanks for the tip, but unfortunately I get this error message: There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 113
STR: '
SQL: UPDATE 'temp` SET time2=NOW() WHERE user = 'kraso' and time1 = (SELECT max(time1) FROM 'temp' where user = 'kraso')`

Comment: Besides the quote issue, it's not clear **which rows you want to update**. Only the rows with the max `time1` (and for a specific user only)? What if there are 2 rows with the same (max) `time1` for that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE temp
SET time2 = NOW() 
WHERE user = 'kraso' 
ORDER BY time1 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there was some trouble with StackOverflow code formatting - It looks like the problem is the use of quotations around the 'temp' in the max select query.

```
(SELECT max(time1) FROM 'temp')
```

Since temp is a table in this case, quotations will not work. Change these single quotations to backticks as shown in the rest of your update statement.

```
UPDATE `temp` SET `time2`=NOW() WHERE user = 'kraso' and time1 = (SELECT max(time1) FROM `temp` where user = 'kraso')
```